# Ruby on Rails time helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timer, form-helpers, recipe

I'm working on my first Rails Application. I am a little stuck with the time. I'm working on a recipe application. I need to add two fields.

- Preparation Time
- Cook Time

Out of the two, i would like to add the two fields to come up with the Total Time needed to prepare the meal.

I approached it the wrong way which doesn't have logic :(. Basically i have two fields and i used f.select to select predefined times. But the problem i have with that approach is that when adding the two, it ignores the Gregorian format e.g 40 minutes + 50 mins will become 90 Min instead of 1hour 30.

I would appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: How exactly are you storing the values in the database? An integer containing the number of minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick example:

```
prep_time = 40.minutes
cook_time = 50.minutes

total_time = prep_time + cook_time
formatted_total_time = Time.at(total_time).gmtime.strftime('%I:%M')

# outputs 01:30 which is HOURS:MINUTES format
```

If you wanted 90 minutes instead:

```
formatted_total_time = total_time / 60

# outputs 90
```

---

Update:

Put this in the helper file associated with whatever view you are using this in (i.e. `app/helpers/recipes_helper.rb`)

```
module RecipesHelper

  def convert_to_gregorian_time(prep_time, cook_time)
    # returns as 90 mins instead of 1hr30mins
    return (prep_time + cook_time) / 60
  end

end
```

Then you'd just call it in your view (i.e. `app/views/recipes/show.html.haml` like:

```
# Note: this is HAML code... but ERB should be similar

%p.cooking_time
  = convert_to_gregorian_time(@recipe.prep_time, @recipe.cook_time)
```

If you are storing the times in the database as integers (which you SHOULD be doing), then you can do this:

```
%p.cooking_time
  = convert_to_gregorian_time(@recipe.prep_time.minutes, @recipe.cook_time.minutes)
```

where `@recipe.prep_time` is an integer with a value of 40 and `@recipe.cook_time` is an integer with a value of 50

and your database schema would look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: recipes
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  prep_time          :integer
#  cook_time          :integer
#  # other fields in the model...
```

Comment: i hear what you are saying but do i use any time helpers. How do i implement the code above?

Comment: See the update answer.  You essentially just create your own helper function and then call it in the view.

Comment: i have tried this but i get the following.  'undefined method `/' for "40.minutes50.minutes":String' then when i remove the /60. I get the two strings printing on my page.

Comment: That's because you aren't inputing the prep and cook times the way that I showed.  Using `50.minutes` is a Ruby method for time, so if you input them as a string that says "50.minutes" it won't work.  The best way to get an understanding of these things is to go into the Rails console (type `rails c` at the terminal / command prompt) and start typing the code above

Comment: What you did was essentially created two strings and then joined the strings using `+`... you have to declare the times like I showed above.  `prep_time = 40.minutes` NOT `prep_time = "40.minutes"`.. There is a big difference between the two

Comment: See my updated answer for a clarification of how you should be doing things